# Detect black & white circles (frog oocytes) in image

Tags: image-processing

I've been trying to count how many cells are in this dish. But I haven't found a successful way because of the presence of withe and black sides in every one.

[image: Oocytes]

I have tried using `EdgeDetect` and `GradientFilter` before applying `Binarize` but they don't discriminate accurately specially where there is many cells.

The original full resolution image can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9COEO.jpg).

```
EdgeDetect[img, {10, 10}, Method -> "Sobel"]
```

[image: Edgedetect]

```
GradientFilter[img, 2]
```

[image: Filter]

For anyone wondering these are frog oocytes.

Update:
I took some pictures with different background and lighting conditions. They can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTVhL.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDkIA.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the code you used to generate the second and third images? It looks like you're almost there.

Comment: And how accurate do you need to be? Have you counted them by hand?

Comment: There should be around 400. I was thinking that I can overlay the original image with a mask of the detected ones and see how many didn't got count.

Comment: By the way, they seem very uniform. Do they all weigh the same? Perhaps you can simply weigh them and divide by the average weight :)

Comment: I don't know how much they weight. The problem is that they cannot be weighted directly because they always have to be in water.

Comment: Aha :) Just a thought!

Comment: Dumb question: Can you control the background? Could you place the petri dish on a green piece of paper? Or even better, a homogeneous light source (backlighting). Better lighting -> easier image processing -> better results.

Comment: You could do a lot better if the source image were taken under different circumstances.  For example, take the photograph against a uniform red background, or some other color not present in the objects to be counted.  Increase the distance between subject and background by elevating the dish using a clear plastic box.  Position a diffuse bright light source close to the subject to reduce shadows.  Increase imaging resolution.  Together these wold make subsequent processing much easier.

Comment: @NikiEstner @heropup Thanks for all your comments, I`ll try to take some new pictures with different background and lighting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With this kind of image, you will not get a perfect estimate of the number of oocytes. There are several ways to approach this, but if you want to do this for more experiments, I would definitely change the setting. Usually, I can talk to my fellow researcher and discuss whether or not something is possible. Since we cannot do this, let me just give you an idea and I let you decide if you want to try it.

One option I see here is to reverse the light settings. Currently, you just take a photo and the light is coming from the room. Change that in the following way:

[image]

What happens with this setting is that your eggs erase the light and since they seem to have the black color *somewhere*, they all should be consistently dark. Furthermore, the hope is that the light shines through the small spaces of the cells and it is then more easy to separate the dark spots they leave on the photo.
Instead of getting headaches because of the black and white eggs, you will get only dark spots. The crucial parts are:

- you need some white paper that acts as diffusor to create a consistently bright underground. It is possible to get rid of inconsistent illumination, but if you can avoid it in the experimental settings, it will be much better
- the room should be dark and the light source beneath the table should be the only light source.
- of course you take a photo *without* the flash

Let me demonstrate this. Experimental setting 1:

- 1 [IKEA GRÖNÖ table lamp](https://www.ikea.com/de/de/catalog/products/20373225/)
- 1 sheet of normal printing paper
- pieces of a Go game (unfortunately no oocytes available)
- 1 mobile phone

With your setting, the image would look like this

[image]

and with the lamp beneath the pieces, it looks like this

[image]

If this works in your case, I assume you will get much better peaks for all of your eggs and I hope, I can convince you that there is a good chance it will highly improve the image processing possibilities.

### More about illumination and removing background

I forgot to mention one important thing we use when we want to have consistent lighting through a whole series of (microscopic) images. If you fix your camera with a tripod and make sure the light source doesn't move, you can remove the background almost completely in a very easy way:

1. Turn the light source on and let it warm up for a while until it doesn't change anymore
2. Prepare your table and camera but don't put the Petri dish on it
3. Now, you take a so-called brightfield image: You make a photo of the table without anything on it. Important is to fix your camera settings. No auto-gain, brightness adjustment, auto-focus, etc. The easiest way is to adjust these settings by making the image of the Petri dish first and you adjust all things to have a nice photo. Then, take the Petri dish away and make the brightfield image from the table only.
4. Now, you can use the brightfield image to subtract the background entirely from your Petri dish image.

A very good tutorial [can be found here](http://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/doku.php?id=howto:working:how_to_correct_background_illumination_in_brightfield_microscopy#acquisition_a_priori_correction) for microscope images. This should work for you as well. I wouldn't bother with the darkfield for the moment but removing the background with the brightfield will save you a lot of pain.

## Your current image

For your current image, it will be hard to separate dark eggs that are close together without losing some of the white sides. Nevertheless, here is my straightforward hack. No optimization, all parameters just trial and error:

Finding the round mask by removing illumination inconsistencies and using the dark Petri dish ring:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUuYL.jpg"]
With[{i = ColorNegate[img]},
 mask = Dilation[Binarize[i - GaussianFilter[i, 100], .08], 3];
 mask = Image@
   Erosion[SelectComponents[FillingTransform[mask], "Area", -1], 40]
 ];
HighlightImage[img, mask]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using a combination of a normal binarization to get an estimate for the egg positions with a local adaptive binarization to get better separated cells.

```
With[{i = ColorConvert[ColorNegate[img], "Grayscale"]},
 m1 = Binarize[GaussianFilter[i, 2] - GaussianFilter[i, 400], .15]*
   mask;
 eggs = Erosion[LocalAdaptiveBinarize[i, 20, {1, 0, 0.1}], 0]*m1
]
```

Using the morphological components to find the center off all detected eggs. If eggs are clustered, there will be one point in the center of many.

```
pos = Values@ComponentMeasurements[
    DeleteSmallComponents[eggs, 3],
    "Medoid"];
HighlightImage[
 img,
 {Red, PointSize[0.005], Point[pos]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `Length[pos]`, we find that there are about 418 eggs in the image. I assume it's more 450-500 as many of the white eggs in crowded places where not recognized. With my proposed setting, I hope the accuracy can be improved.

Comment: This is a great answer.  (I hope you get paid well for what you must bring to your job.)  It goes way beyond the original question and adds in your extensive experience (rather than just providing a grammatically correct response).  OK, enough sappiness for now.

Comment: `Erosion` seems a bit superfluous, especially the one with kernel size 0 ;)

Comment: @JimB "I hope you get paid well for what you must bring to your job." -- That is borderline offensive. I would have assumed he is independently wealthy. (Consider his location and how much time he spends posting/moderating MSE and working on IntelliJ's Mathematica plug-in...)

Comment: @AntonAntonov You are correct.  I should have learned by now (especially with this forum) not to make assumptions.  But I just wanted to express my gratitude.

Comment: @AntonAntonov No, I was not offended! Jim and I are kind of in the same boat: We get *usually* called when the experiment is done and there is a famous quote I love: "To call in the statistician after the experiment is done may be no more than asking him to perform a post-mortem examination: he may be able to say what the experiment died of." [ref](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/739/36404)
People who worked with me more than once know this and learned to ask for advice to ensure we can actually do something with the data after the experiment.

Comment: @C.E. You are right :) I tried to see if opening up the binarization separates eggs but too many small objects got lost. Forgot to take it out.

Comment: @JimB My statement was not supposed to be accepted that seriously. I was trying to say: **1)** yes halirutan knows a lot and he is very prolific, but probably he is "working for the same reason that a hen goes on laying eggs"; **2)** many Western European countries allow their citizens to have financially content lives, so they do not necessary measure life quality with money. (Like, say, people in some "blind capitalism" fetishizing countries do.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov.  I appreciate the clarification.  And I promise to take you less seriously from now on.  (Sorry, I had to throw in my feeble attempt at humor.)  But seriously, I really do appreciate your response.  One of the best things about this forum is that one has their norms (both scientific and occasionally social) frequently challenged.  It's the only way to grow.

Comment: @BPinto Please note that I have added a small section about removing the background with a brightfield image in the middle.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an estimate. There are definitely better ways to do this, perhaps someone else will shed more light.

First I crop the image, just for the sake of having smaller search space.

```
i2 = ImageCrop@
  ImageMultiply[i, 
   ImageResize[ImagePad[Image@DiskMatrix[75], 25], ImageDimensions@i]]
```

[image: cropped input]

Next, I crop a single match out of the image.

[image: match]

Now I divide the image into parts roughly the size of my `match`, and determine the distance between the `match` and each of these parts.

```
dists = MapAt[
   ImageDistance[#, ColorConvert[match, "Grayscale"], 
     DistanceFunction -> "MeanPatternIntensity"] &, 
   ImagePartition[ColorConvert[i2, "Grayscale"], 
    UpTo[ImageDimensions@match*0.9]], {All, All}];
```

This gives us a list that looks like this:

[image: distance arrayplot]

Then, we binarize the list and count the components.

```
components = 
 SelectComponents[
  Binarize[Image@
    dists], #Elongation < .7 && #AdjacentBorderCount == 0 &]
```

`Total@components` gives us 463. I haven't manually counted but it seems semi-correct.

If we overlay the two, we can see roughly what's getting counted:

[image: overlaid]

Other, probably more rigorous methods might involve `ImageCorrelate`. You could also probably train a neural network to do it if you came up with a clever way to generate training data, but that's more of a weekend project :)

Good luck!